# Microsoft Edge Browser keeps crashing

Tags: microsoft-edge

My default page in MS Edge is Google. When I load Edge, I can see the google URL in the address bar, then it changes to this

> ms-appx-web:///assets/errorpages/acr_error.htm#http://www.google.co.uk/

and then Edge disappears. It's clearly crashed but I don't see any warning or message.

Even if after Edge opens I hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> loads (to stop it loading/processing) it still crashes.

Despite how quickly I try, when I open Edge and I try to open settings or similar, no windows show - it just crashes as explained above

Application under Event View shows

```
Faulting application name: microsoftedgecp.exe, version: 11.0.14393.953, time stamp: 0x58ba5911
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000001b1fa2b0011
Faulting process ID: 0x2934
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3047308e8116e
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoftedgecp.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report ID: 63cde917-9695-4910-a45e-f0f252c7dbd4
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_38.14393.1066.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: MicrosoftEdge
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

I did a chckdsk and it found no errors or vunrabilities ( I can't remember the exact message).

I restart the computer and it's working. After a while (< 1 hour) of moderate use (using only GitHub and Visual Studio) the same issue returns. A restart appears to fix it temporaly.

Comment: To address the actual question: Have you tried clearing the browser cache and cookies?

Comment: How @JeffZeitlin. As I mentioned, I can't get into any settings in Edge. I've attempted this via IE though

Comment: I'm not on a Windows 10 computer at the moment, but on earlier versions of Windows, one could go into the Internet Options control panel and do it from there. That might also be a way to change the default (a.k.a. "home") page as well, which might let you get into the browser to check settings and cache.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I wouldn't be at all. I'd just tell you, that it won't run on my OS. That's of course different to my suggestion of trying another brwoser, which actually does run on W10.

Comment: <sigh> not using Edge isn't an acceptable solution to the author's problem of being unable to start Edge.  If that's all you have to bring to the table that's not an acceptable answer

Comment: I should note that the only time I see this sort of suggestion is when the querent is using Microsoft products, and the "suggestion" is coming from an anti-Microsoft bigot.

Answer (score 6):

This was happening to me too. Literally as I was writing this post I came across a Technet link and it's now fixed!

**Error:**

```
Faulting application name: MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe, version: 11.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0x59cda7cd
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.16299.19, time stamp: 0x4f438703
Exception code: 0x8000ffff
Fault offset: 0x000000000064c834
Faulting process ID: 0x2f54
Faulting application start time: 0x01d346ea44a23ac8
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll
Report ID: 902ddd65-50c3-48c8-81d1-d6e6c3c6d447
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_41.16299.15.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: ContentProcess
```

**Solution:**
Run the following in an elevated Command Prompt:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Spartan" /v RAC_LaunchFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4af16a6b-00fb-452f-91dd-d384a4b0797a/microsoft-edge-crashes-on-windows-10-version-1703?forum=win10itprogeneral

Comment: This fixed it for me when I tried 5 other solutions. Thanks @toastpaint!