# Microsoft Edge becomes unresponsive with the window a ghostly white when applying fonts and font-styles in the Outlook web app

Tags: outlook.com, outlook-web-access, microsoft-edge

Yesterday Microsoft Edge became unresponsive on multiple occasions,  with the screen a ghostly white, when I was trying to apply font changes to selected text in the Outlook web app. Each time it happened Edge stayed that way for several minutes until I was given the option to close it.  If this is a known issue and there's a way to fix the problem, please advise. Thanks

Comment: Someway related: https://superuser.com/q/1714784/152004, https://superuser.com/q/1233872/152004

Comment: Funny. A question I asked on Superuser the other day, about web Outlook, was migrated to Web Applications Stack Exchange.

Comment: In general, troubleshooting like questions are off-topic on [webapps.se] but troubleshooting questions about installable software, like a web-browser might be on-topic here.